# If we throw the dice once a then we throw a coin the amount of times that the dice shows, what is the probability that there will be 5 tails?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

To extend the heading (problem):

We are throwing the dice a can get numbers from **1** - **6**. If number **1** is shown on the dice then we throw the coin once. If number **2** is show on the dice we throw the coin 2 times... If number **6** is shown on the dice then we throw the coin 6 times. What is the probability of getting exactly **5 tails**?

Attempt:
We can get 5 tails only if we get number **5** or number **6** on the dice.

- if we get number 5 on the dice then we must get all the tails to match this probability: $(\frac{1}{2})^5$
- if we get number 6 then we can get 5 times tails as well and one time heads
  $(\frac{1}{2})^6$

By adding these two probabilities I don't get my result:
[image]

Comment: For your second case, the $H$ can be in any of the $6$ trials, so you have to multiply by $6$.

Comment: Note: you also need to multiply each of your two probabilities by $\frac 16$ as you first need to get the requisite die throw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it into disjoint events, and then add up their probabilities:

$$\sum\limits_{n=5}^{6}\frac16\cdot\binom{n}{5}\cdot\left(\frac12\right)^{5}\cdot\left(1-\frac12\right)^{n-5}=\frac{1}{48}$$

Comment: isn't the anser 1/8=1/32+6/64

Comment: @wesewx: Sounds to me like you're forgetting to take into consideration the chances of getting $5$ or $6$ on the die (i.e., you should multiply each one of those terms by $\frac16$).

Answer (score 1):

> - if we get number 6 then we can get 5 times tails as well and one time heads
>     $(\frac{1}{2})^6$

There are six ways to get $5$ tails and $1$ head. Note that the head can come in the first place, in the second, etc.

Comment: I, see, do I have to multiply $(\frac{1}{2})^6*6$?

Comment: Yes, and you also have to decide whether to read the problem as accepting six tails.  Do we need at least five tails or exactly five tails?  That is an English question, not a math one.  If six tails is acceptable, you have to add that case in.  I think the question is ambiguous.

Comment: O i got it now basicaly i can write 6/64 +1/32

Comment: The answer is 0.125 or 1/8...